# I have a stuck transaction (2 days already)

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

I have this transaction :

https://blockchain.info/tx/8fdb3e8a0a33b3d1721b6ef7c1c2608b1e1a8aacd8857e22287b120c09ee988a

I understand it's stuck because of the low value i spended but look at the fee.

Do you know how much time it will take to be confirmed ?

Can i do somthing to make it confirm faster ?

I was thinkig to merge it with this one :

https://blockchain.info/tx/25f232656860a196b3e694275cc217c6382f638230663de13946ba5e4df80a1d

Is it possible ?

Comment: It looks like there is some strange stuff going on here, did you see this note: "This transaction has a very small output and is none standard."  Do you own the address [15DkCkxCDE6aUNNSLHyDRCDARiRBwSHmbk](https://blockchain.info/address/15DkCkxCDE6aUNNSLHyDRCDARiRBwSHmbk)?

Comment: There is no need to put a "[solved]" marker into your question text. Since you've accepted an answer, you've already marked this question as "solved".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the amount being sent (`0.0000024 BTC`) might have been too small and therefore below the "dust threshold" [listed in this old thread](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/6793#issuecomment-147089803) as `0.00002730 BTC` when `minrelayfee` = `0.00005` for a normal transaction. Here is [the code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/28ad4d9fc2be102786a8c6c32ebecb466b2a03dd/src/primitives/transaction.h#L161) that determines what is "dust".  Comment says:

```
// "Dust" is defined in terms of CTransaction::minRelayTxFee,
// which has units satoshis-per-kilobyte.
// If you'd pay more than 1/3 in fees
// to spend something, then we consider it dust.
// A typical spendable txout is 34 bytes big, and will
// need a CTxIn of at least 148 bytes to spend:
// so dust is a spendable txout less than
// 546*minRelayTxFee/1000 (in satoshis)
```

Note: A [previous transaction with exact same fee but larger outputs](https://blockchain.info/tx/61ef08eef99e74f9dd6037c6aff3b8b0703fd86371c259a6c4b6bfd2cd7eacf3) went through just fine.

Comment: Is it stuck forever ?

Comment: Does it effect my other transitions ?

Comment: The other transactions that you made after that one from the same address will be dependent on it.  You could try to double-spend as @jonas-schnelli suggested.

If using Blockchain.info, probably best to contact their tech support for help.

Comment: but when i double spend do i need to spend more in the fees ?

Comment: will Blockchain.info they cancel it  ?

Comment: And what should i write to them

Comment: Your transaction was cleared, all should be good now: https://blockchain.info/address/15DkCkxCDE6aUNNSLHyDRCDARiRBwSHmbk

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction is using a extremely low fee (0.0001 BTC for 226 bytes).
It might never confirm.

What you should try to do is double-spend your own transaction with a higher fee.
You just need to try to create a transaction with the same input: 61ef08eef99e74f9dd6037c6aff3b8b0703fd86371c259a6c4b6bfd2cd7eacf3/vout:1 and maybe the same output but a higher fee (less change).

Comment: thx for comment if i have more transion that i made which arent conifrmed too if the one i mntion here wont be confirmed will it affect them ?

Comment: is double spending safe ?

Comment: `0.0001 BTC` for 226 bytes is not super low, I was able to send 2 such transactions yesterday and both confirmed immediately.  According to https://bitcoinfees.21.co - This fee should generally confirm within 0-1 blocks (0-45 min) on average.  The optimal fee of `0.0000006 BTC` / byte would be just `0.0001356 BTC`.  I think there may be something else blocking this transaction.

Comment: In the first one it says the transiction has a very small output and its none standard and the two other i did with higer values it says "the transiction is spending an input which is unconfirmed" , will they ever go through ?